# is there any python code to aggregate the dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, format

I am trying to aggregate my data frame for a better look outcome, using python. Is there any way to aggregate the column? Fom this:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 3 4
1 3 4
```

to this:

```
1 2 3
    3 
  3 4
    4
```

Comment: Set your columns as index.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Please read about `groupby()`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html